# Static Public IP

Tags: isp

I am having a problem to get a static public IP. I am using a residential internet connection from a local provider and the provided IP may be a shared connection. When I change my router the provided public IP change automatically. I have configured three computers though my router, all of them have the same public IP. But I am getting failed to open my port 80 in the router when i am trying set my own hosting website. I am using d-link dir-615 firmwire 20.22 n300 router. It doesn't have port forwarding option but vertual server. I have opened port 80 in my router and in inbound rules but when i check the port open or not it says connection refused. I have configured the firewall as default for Domain, Private and Public and the IE enhanced security configuration in server manager is turned off. How can I solve this problem to open my port 80 in the router ? How can I get a Public IP only for me ?

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? Please don't do that, read and take note of [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers). If you have new information you should edit it into the original question instead of asking a new one.

Comment: Speak to your ISP.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, residential internet service providers (ISPs) do not give static IP addresses to home users.  They have a block of dynamically assigned IPs.  If you want a static IP, you will have to pay for a "business" class of service.  Similarly, port 80 is often blocked for residential customers, as running a web server is a business use in the ISPs eyes.  If you want to use port 80, more than likely you will have to pay for a "business" class service.  Obviously, contact your ISP and/or others servicing your area to see what is offered.

Comment: Thanks for the reply mr. Keltari, I forgot to mention a thing that i have checked the public IP in providers website where i found that my IP is a business class service.

Comment: @DewanMusa You arent understanding what I am saying.  It doesnt matter if you are a business, you dont have that level of service. 
 Talk to your ISP.  More than likely you will have to pay extra money to get a static IP.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the solution. one more thing may I know how can i get sure that the provided Public IP is shared ?

Comment: my ip information looks like this --  ip: "103.106.---.--"
 city: ""
 region: ""
 country: "BD"
 loc: "23.7000,90.3750"
 asn: Object
 asn: "AS137278"
 name: "1 Touch BD Online Ltd."
 domain: ""
 route: "103.106.---.0/24"
 type: "business"
 company: Object
 name: "1 Touch BD Online Ltd."
 domain: ""
 type: "business"

Comment: this will be my last comment:  TALK TO YOUR ISP